Lisp Macro that can take Forth like order
I am studdying Lisp after many years of C like languages (C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript, Go, Haxe).
I've written already some usefull programs with Lisp, and I feel already productive enough with it, I've utilized some basic macros too keep my codebase cleaner, and to easily move from lisp to lisp.
Even After realizing that S-EXPR and unified prefix are not as bad as strangers think about them, I can still not fool myself that some problems are naturally expressed as a chain of procedures, and I feel that my eyes are limiting me when having to read it back and forwards.
I wonder if someone already made a macro that would transform code such as
(F myvar 1 + go 3 * go print go)

to
(print (* 3 (+ myvar 1)))

This is an over simplified example, I am actually dealing with replacing a regex in a string with the result fo a lamabda function call.
Or are there any other solutions to that problem?

I found this blog that seems to have what you're looking for: https://blog.fugue88.ws/archives/2022-03/Pipelines-in-Lisp
